# TypeScript error: Cannot find module 'moment'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, momentjs

I have a TypeScript React app using `npx create-react-app --template typescript`. When I run `npm start`, I get an error in one of my files:

```
TypeScript error in /<path>/App.tsx:
Cannot find module 'moment'.  TS2307
```

Import:

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "husky.config.js", "lint-staged.config.js"]
}
```

Using `"moment": "^2.25.0"` in `package.json`. Using npm.

Looking in the `node_modules` directory, I can see the `moment` package, and the `package.json` file says `moment` is on version 2.25.0

I've tried clearing npm cache, deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, reinstalling, importing like `import * as moment from 'moment'`.

Any ideas? This just randomly started happening today. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you change anything in the code that made this error appear? is the import used differently?

Comment: maybe you should post your `package.json` as well

Comment: I am also having the same issue here, I replaced `import {Moment} from '../../moment/moment';` Now it works, but I don't know why it doesn't work when `import {Moment} from 'moment';` It's happening in angular charts module by the way.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with moment version 2.25.0. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5486. Try using 2.24.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update**

moment version 2.25.1 is released. This fixes the issue.

**Old Answer**

It's an issue of moment version 2.25.0,

https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/5486

Delete your **package-lock.json** and **node_modules** folder, replace this line of code in your **package.json**

```
"moment": "2.24.0",
```

note, remove the *^*, else it will keep installing 2.25.0

then **npm install**

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install a package before actually using it in your code. So you can Install moment library using npm (node package manager)

`npm install moment`

and then import this library

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

Then you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You have done exactly right, nothing wrong in the scaffolding the app. Just a mistake in the import statement as it has been updated.

As of version **2.13.0**, Moment includes a typescript definition file.

Install via NPM
npm install moment

Import and use in your Typescript file-

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
let now = moment().format('LLLL');
```

**Note:** If you have trouble importing moment
For *Typescript 2.x* try adding  `"moduleResolution": "node"` in `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file(in your app root directory) and then use any of the below syntax

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import moment = require('moment');
```

For *Typescript 1.x* try adding `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json` file and then use the syntax

```
import moment from 'moment';
let now = moment().format('LLLL');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. npm install moment
2. **delete node_modules** <--- if you still found error
3. **then npm i** <--- install the package again
4. and then import this library
   import * as moment from 'moment'